# retractable helicopter pump

Tags: inventorship

In reference to the patent: [US20100178176](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100178176)

Hello,

I'm trying to find the original designers of the retractable helicopter pump and either get in contact with them or who is the current commercial builder/owner.

Can you assist in how I can contact these gentlemen?

Answer (score 0):

Try the correspondence adress here:
EDIT: Link doesnt work and the uspto website has trouble finding the page for the patent, thats ... annoying. Well, click on the google link in your question and on USPTO on the right side there (next to espacenet), that worked for me. There is an adress there.

And bear in mind that this patent has not been granted (and does not have to be granted).